# How to resume the dataTask with some partial data stored in fileManager?

Tags: ios, swift

Want to use some function like  downloadTask(withResumeData:), but want to achieve it using dataTask

I have a partially downloaded file, stored in FileManager want to download its rest of the dat, but don’t want to download the already downloaded data.

Comment: How can I make a function like downloadTask(withResumeData:) for dataTask?

Comment: How to do this task in Swift ?https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/307548/Resume-Suppoert-Downloading

Comment: how did you do resuming?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make make a mutableURLRequest and can inform it with your partial data like this

```
    let webRequest = MutableURLRequest(url: downloadURL)
    var range = "bytes="
    range = range + ("\(self.fileSize)") + ("-")
    webRequest.addValue(range, forHTTPHeaderField: "Range")
```